# How do I add and remove children in div based on position?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visibility

My following code is: http://jsfiddle.net/j67AM/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="data">
        <div>some random text</div>
        <div>more random text</div>
        <div>random</div>
        <div>text</div>
        <div>sdads</div>
        <div>sdads</div>
        <div>sdads</div>
        <div>sdads</div>
        <div>sdads</div>
        <div>sdads</div>
        <div>sdads</div>
        <div>sdads</div>
        <div>sdads</div>
        <div>sdads</div>
        <div>sdads</div>
        <div>sdads</div>
        <div>sdads</div>
        <div>sdads</div>
        <div>sdads</div>
        <div>sdads</div>
        <div>sdads</div>
        <div>sdads</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```css
#container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

What would be the best approach in JavaScript to remove every div that is not visible? and to then add the div if it becomes visible.

For example if I were to add 3000 div in the "data" then it will more than likely "lag" the page so I'm trying to come up with a solution that will only render the content that is visible inside the container.

Thanks

Comment: Are the divs hidden by CSS?

Comment: What you appear to be looking for is called "lazy loading." There are several jQuery plugins that do this, but I'm not familiar offhand with a script that's pure Javascript.

Comment: No... the div's are not hidden and yes I know it requires some kind of JavaScript but unsure on how to do it. Though for the scroll bar not to mess up I would probably need to replace the div with just blank lines or something.